# use image from gitlab Registry in CI

Tags: docker, gitlab

Could you tell me if I do it in correct way:

- I have create Docker image with all stuff which is need for running my tests in gitlab CI
- I push it to gitlab registry
- I can see on gitlab page in section Registry my image - **gitlablogin/projectname**
- I want to use this image for CI, so in .gitlab-ci.yml I add image: **gitlablogin/projectname**

Before I had had in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
same_task:
  stage: deploy
  image: python:3
  script:
    - python -V
```

Now I have:

```
pep8:
  stage: deploy
  image: gitlablogin/projectname
  script:
    - python -V
```

and after this change job failed:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.4.2 (cf91d5e1)
  on docker-auto-scale 72989761
Using Docker executor with image gitlablogin/projectname ...
Pulling docker image gitlablogin/projectname ...
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gitlablogin/projectname, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' (executor_docker.go:168:0s)
```

Is my usage of docker in context of gitlab CI and gitlab registry is correct? I also want to keep my docker file on same repo and build new image when samething change in Dockerfile, what will be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach isn't far from what you want to achieve. I believe what you are missing is this:

According to: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-an-image

in order to use the image you have built for your CI you will first need to add it to runner's ***config.toml*** file as a ***service***.

Once you have done so you would be able to use the directive: `image: my_image`

However, there's another option which you could do: you could login to your Docker registry, pull and run the CI Docker image and then you can exec inside where you will be running your pipeline.

Answer (score 13):

Right now it is possible to use images from your gitlab registry without any special steps. Just build and push an image to your gitlab project container registry

```
docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/gitlabProject/projectName:build .
docker push registry.gitlab.com/gitlabProject/projectName:build
```

and then just specify this image in your pipeline settings:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlabProject/projectName:build
```

Gitlab is able to pull this image using it's credentials:

```
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:46
 Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlabProject/projectName:build ...
 Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
 Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/gitlabProject/projectName:build ...
 Using docker image sha256:e7e0f4f5fa8cff8a93b1f37ffd7dd0505946648246aa921dd457c06a1607304b for registry.gitlab.com/gitlabProject/projectName:build ...
```

More: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#support-for-gitlab-integrated-registry

Comment: It was also necessary to go to **Settings** -> **CI/CD** -> **Token Access** and add access for project that wanted to use image.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing needed to access docker images from another project on the same gitlab instance is that your project is allowed for Token Access on the project with the image.

No other configuration like docker login is needed. Just use `image: $CI_REGISTRY/other/project:tag`

```yaml
job-in-project1:
  stage: test
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/group-b/otherproject:latest
  script:
    - command to run with docker image
```

Configuration:

- Go to the project wich contains the image in its Container Registry. e.g. `group-b/otherproject`
- Open Settings > CI/CD
- Expand "Token Access"
- in **Allow CI job tokens from the following projects to access this project** click "Add Project"

[image: Allow Token Access from your project]

Documentation: https://git.aviloo.com/help/ci/jobs/ci_job_token#configure-cicd-job-token-access

Answer (score 2):

It helped me
Open Settings -> CI/CD -> Token Access and add project to panel "Allow CI job tokens from the following projects to access this project"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. That's the correct, easy solution. The only thing needed to access docker images from another project on the same gitlab instance is that your project is allowed for Token access on the project with the image. No other configuration like docker login is needed. Just use `image: $CI_REGISTRY/other/project:latest` after configuring Token access on /other/project to `mygroup/myproject`